# How to read Spark SQL's toDebugString output?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I can't find out how to read Spark SQL's onDebugString output.
I don't understand

- what those #number are near column names
- what true or false mean near Aggregate or Sort (eg. Sort [l_returnflag#404 ASC,l_linestatus#405 ASC], true)
- what BuildLeft or BuildRight mean on ShuffledHashJoin
- why there are !OutputFaker lines when quering Parquet databases and what they do mean

Here are links to toDebugString outputs for the same query on two different database formats.

Avro http://pastebin.com/BPwwfdzz

Parquet http://pastebin.com/pZNfCHPc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. #number is part of name (DataFrame internal field representation). DataFrame allows to have two fields with the same name (they have different #number). There'll be issue trying to select one of them - you'll get it's ambiguous.
2. Aggregate / Sort true / false. True means it's local operation. In your examples you can see that there is always Aggregate true, then Exchange, then Aggregate false. It means there is some aggregation happened locally on each node for each partition, then nodes exchanges their hashes to know where to send data and then aggregation finishes on remote nodes.
3. BuildLeft and BuildRight, I can only speculate that's join sides. By doing a join you always have two parts you join - left and right. That's it.
4. Cannot tell what's OutputFaker is, but for completeness the javadoc says:

   > A plan node that does nothing but lie about the output of its child.  Used to spice a
   >   (hopefully structurally equivalent) tree from a different optimization sequence into an already
   >   resolved tree.

Most of the operations say for themselves like Filtering or Exchange, but sometimes it's important to know the difference: ShuffledHashJoin vs BroadcastHashJoin. That's in my mind why explain is helpful.

Additionally, it's possible to print explain with details (not only physical plan), just call *explain(true)*.